# Exporting values in numeric format from R to excel

Tags: r

I have used `melt`, `gather` and `as.numeric` functions to convert the format of the values before saving the data in excel from R. But none of them is seeing to give numeric output. All are producing text formats. On checking the `class` of the values, R is showing `factor`.

```
#To convert from wide to long
long <- melt(dd, id.vars = "date")
long$value <- as.numeric(long$value)
long_gather <- gather(dd, "variable", "value", -date, convert = TRUE) 

write.xlsx(dd, "ddf.xlsx",sheetName="wide", col.names=T, 
showNA = F; Append = TRUE)
```

Using `melt` and `as.numeric` is changing the values entirely (the 4th column) and the `gather` function is returning the values but in text format (4th column) on being saved in excel.

Can someone help me on how to get the correct format in excel?

Comment: Isn't `write.csv` good enough? What of `openxlsx::write.xlsx`? It is better to include in your question what code you used and what data you're trying to export.

Comment: Hi, added the code. `write.csv` will give only text output.

Comment: Could you add some kind of sample output?

Comment: Added the output.

Comment: Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to write numbers with a lot of decimals in Excel and Excel considers the cells as numbers. This approach only works on Windows.

```
library(RDCOMClient)
path_Excel_File1 <- "D:\\test_File_1.xlsx"

xlApp <- COMCreate("Excel.Application")
xlApp[["Visible"]] <- TRUE
xlWbk <- xlApp$Workbooks()$Open(path_Excel_File1)
Sheets <- xlWbk$Sheets()

vec_Val <- c(9.012323453534523543529035443025435, 10.01242354325243653476874582354,
             11.12403252345635456534673546354634, 10.234213452435654623524536546)

nb_Val <- length(vec_Val)

for(i in 1 : nb_Val)
{
  cell_Obj <- Sheets[[1]]$Cells(1, i)
  cell_Obj[["Value"]] <- vec_Val[i]
}
```